# d3 - Update Width and X for smooth transition in Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js

Edit: Not sure why the bars are not showing up! Just after how to get the update animation to work on this visualization, using width and x to update the bars after an arc is selected!

I've got a horizontal stacked bar chart that I am trying to update smoothly as seen in this verticle example (https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/7e3ec1a6722a153a5d102b6c42f4501d). I am struggling to get it to work. I have tried using CSS and transitioning the 'width' attribute but it doesn't work as intended. I was wondering if someone might be able to help.

How it works is that if you select one of the arcs, the data would be recalculated. Can you aid me?

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 800;

const svg = d3.select('#radial-chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);


const arc = d3.arc()

const handleMouseOver = (d, i, n) => {
  svg.selectAll('path')
    .transition().duration(300)
    .style('opacity', 0.35);

  d3.select(n[i])
    .transition().duration(300)
    .style('opacity', 0.35)
}

const handleMouseOut = (d, i, n) => {
  svg.selectAll('path')
    .transition().duration(300)
    .style('opacity', 0.35)
    .style('stroke-width', 0)

}


var arcData = [{
    domain: '1',
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: (h / 1.75),
    startAngle: Math.PI * -20 / 180,
    endAngle: Math.PI * 20 / 180
  },
  {
    domain: '2',
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: (h / 2),
    startAngle: Math.PI * 20 / 180,
    endAngle: Math.PI * 60 / 180
  }
];

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["1", "2"])
  .range(["#E8A82B", "#000000"]);
const slices = arcData.map(d => arc(d));


svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(slices)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(325,550)')
  .attr("d", d => d)
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "arc" + i)
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i))
  .style("z-index", 100)
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  // .attr('class', 'selected')
  .on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
  .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).classed("selected", d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? false : true)
    d3.select('image#arc' + i).classed("selected", d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? true : false)
  })

//Bar
const bar1 = d3.select('#bar1').append('svg').attr('width', 800).attr('height', 175);

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#02029D", "#223AAF", '#446FBD', '#669CCB']);

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, 800]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([200])

var n_sumSeventyk = 500,
  n_sum71kto149k = 600,
  n_sum150kto249k = 200,
  n_sum250k = 100

if ($('path#arc0').hasClass('selected') === true) {
  var n_sumSeventyk = n_sumSeventyk - 100,
    n_sum71kto149k = n_sum71kto149k - 300,
    n_sum150kto249k = n_sum150kto249k - 25,
    n_sum250k = n_sum250k - 65
} else {}

if ($('path#arc1').hasClass('selected') === true) {
  var n_sumSeventyk = n_sumSeventyk - 75,
    n_sum71kto149k = n_sum71kto149k - 200,
    n_sum150kto249k = n_sum150kto249k - 90,
    n_sum250k = n_sum250k - 80
} else {};

var bar1Data = [{
    position: 1,
    label: '70k',
    value: n_sumSeventyk
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: n_sum71kto149k
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: n_sum150kto249k
  },
  {
    position: 4,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: n_sum250k
  }
];

//sort bars based on value
bar1Data = bar1Data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.descending(a.value, b.value);
})



d3.interval(function() {
  var n_sumSeventyk = 600;
  if ($('path#arc0').hasClass('selected') === true) {
    var n_sumSeventyk = n_sumSeventyk - 100
    var bar1Data = [{
        position: 1,
        label: '70k',
        value: n_sumSeventyk
      },
      {
        position: 2,
        label: '71K - 149K',
        value: n_sum71kto149k
      },
      {
        position: 3,
        label: '71K - 149K',
        value: n_sum150kto249k
      },
      {
        position: 4,
        label: '71K - 149K',
        value: n_sum250k
      },
    ];
  } else {
    var n_sumSeventyk = n_sumSeventyk
    var bar1Data = [{
        position: 1,
        label: '70k',
        value: n_sumSeventyk,
      },
      {
        position: 2,
        label: '71K - 149K',
        value: n_sum71kto149k
      },
      {
        position: 3,
        label: '71K - 149K',
        value: n_sum150kto249k
      },
      {
        position: 4,
        label: '71K - 149K',
        value: n_sum250k
      },
    ];
  }



  update(bar1Data)
}, 400)

update(bar1Data)
;

bar1.append("text")
  .attr("x", (400))
  .attr("y", 80)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style('font-family', 'marsBook')
  .style("font-size", "24px")
  .text("Household Income")


function update(bar1Data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.sum(bar1Data, d => d.value)])
  y.domain([0, d3.max(bar1Data).value])

  //Join data to rects

  const rects = bar1.selectAll('rect')
    .data(bar1Data)

  rects.exit().remove();

  rects.attr('width', (d) => {
      return x(d.value)
    })
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('class', (d, i) => {
      return 'bar' + i
    })
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return x(sum(bar1Data.map((e) => e.value), 0, i));
    })
    .attr('y', 100)


  rects.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', (d) => {
      return x(d.value)
    })
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('x', (d, i) => {
      // Note that I use `.map` here to take only the `.value` attribute
      // from the data and create an array of numbers. Then I pass it to `x`
      // to be transformed (could also be the other way around if you'd like,
      // so sum(bar1Data.map((e) => x(e.value)), 0, i)
      return x(sum(bar1Data.map((e) => e.value), 0, i));
    })
    .attr('y', 100)
    .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i))



  function sum(array, start, end) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) total += array[i];
    return total;
  }
  console.log(bar1Data)
}
```

```css
}

/* Header */
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding: 0.781vw 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
p {
  font-family: MarsBook;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
header h1 {
  color: #0000a0;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  font-family: marsBold;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
header p {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  color: #00dcfa;
}
header .subtitle {
  margin-left: 0.5vw;
  font-family: marsBold;
  font-size: 2vw;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#bars {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: 100000000000000000000
}
#bars h1 {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.selected {
  opacity: 1!important
}
image#arc0,
image#arc1,
image#arc2,
image#arc3,
image#arc4,
image#arc5,
image#arc6,
image#arc7,
image#arc8 {
  opacity: 0.35
}
image#arc0:hover,
image#arc1:hover,
image#arc2:hover,
image#arc3:hover,
image#arc4:hover,
image#arc5:hover,
image#arc6:hover,
image#arc7:hover,
image#arc8:hover {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='radial-chart'></div>
<div id='bar1'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using CSS on the rects on the dom.

```
rect {
    transition: width 0.3s, x 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition:  x 0.3s, width 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:  width 0.3s, x 0.3s ease;
}
```